# Scroll content in div

Tags: javascript, html, css, marquee

I use  tag to scroll content in a div. but my content width is more than the div width size and some parts of the content goes to second line. any solution to keep all the content in the same line?

Answer (score 2):

The question is what do want to *do* with the overflowed content. Is it text, images or something else?

If its text, you can either get a nice ending with three dots using `text-overflow:ellipsis;` or clip it using `text-overflow:clip;` With other elements you can use `overflow:hidden;`.

Otherwise you can use scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with CSS's [overflow-x](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp) property:

```
tag{
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div {overflow:scroll;}
```

This will make your div scrollable horizontaly an verticaly.You don`t need to care about your content.

But if you have space try increasing it`s width using css.

Answer (score 0):

To keep content inline use **white-space:nowrap;** and to bring horizontal scroll you should use **overflow-x:auto** along with **fixed width to div**.

Here you go:

> jsfiddle.net/aR26p/